# Como fazer para um container Docker resolver um nome DNS do HOST?

Tags: docker

No meu servidor HOST coloco no arquivo /etc/hosts a entrada:

```
192.168.9.9 server_1
```

Preciso que de dentro de um container docker, se eu chamar:
 `wget server_1:1234` ,  ele acesse a porta 1234 do ip 192.168.9.9  (é o IP do HOST) onde o docker está instalado.
**Não posso usar a diretiva --networks = host**
Seria possível criar um serviço ou editar o iptables do host?

Comment: Conseguiu experimentar o add-host?

Answer (score 3):

Nesse caso é preciso alterar o hosts do container e não do host. A maneira correta de "alterar" o arquivo hosts do container é com a flag `--add-host`, conforme a documentação do docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Nesse seu caso, ainda é preciso verificar o IP na "rede" do docker e não o IP do host na rede em que o mesmo se encontra. Esse IP varia confirme o seu sistema operacional, mas vc pode consultá-lo e alterá-lo mas configurações do docker.